# Отсутствует модуль sklearn.cross_validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

**Ошибка:** В примере был модуль `sklearn.cross_validation`. Модуль отсутсвует и программа не работает. Пробовал заменить на `sklearn.model_selection` но программа ведет себя неадекватно.

**Код:**

```
# simulate splitting a dataset of 25 observations into 5 folds
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=False)

# print the contents of each training and testing set
print('{} {:^61} {}'.format('Iteration', 
                            'Training set observations', 
                            'Testing set observations'))
for iteration, data in enumerate(kf, start=1):
    print('{:^9} {} {!s:^25}'.format(iteration, data[0], data[1]))
```

**Вывод:**
*`TypeError: 'KFold' object is not iterable`*

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-13995db0f7c7> in <module>()
        5 # print the contents of each training and testing set
        6 print('{} {:^61} {}'.format('Iteration', 'Training set 
observations', 'Testing set observations'))
  ----> 7 for iteration, data in enumerate(kf, start=1):
        8     print('{:^9} {} {!s:^25}'.format(iteration, data[0], data[1]))

TypeError: 'KFold' object is not iterable
```

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

Answer (score 1):

Игорь, спасибо!

В классе cross_validation был параметр y (Samples to split in K folds):

class sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=3, shuffle=False, random_state=None)[source]

Именно его мне и не хватало в model_selection

Если сделать так, то все встает на свои места

```
# simulate splitting a dataset of 25 observations into 5 folds
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
Vec = np.arange(0,26)
# print the contents of each training and testing set
print('{} {:^61} {}'.format('Iteration', 
                            'Training set observations', 
                            'Testing set observations'))
for iteration, data in enumerate(kf.split(Vec), start=1):
   print('{:^9} {} {!s:^25}'.format(iteration, data[0], data[1]))
```